# How can I receive the PayPal express field "Notes to Seller" or "Instructions to Merchant" that the user enters?

Tags: payment, paypal-express

I have PayPal express on my Magento website

How can I receive the PayPal express field "Notes to Seller" or "Instructions to Merchant" that the user enters?

I can't seem to see that information anywhere in Magento.

Comment: Not sure if and how you can retrieve this information via PayPal API. Which Magento version do you use? Maybe there is an option to activate to show these details in the order view?

Comment: I do not believe that info is transmitted via IPN.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a look at the PayPal IPN data from the [PayPal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).

There are no fields for those two values so they won't be available in the shop.